# Saving tuple rows to csv in python without blank rows?

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have read many questions and answers here about how to do this. But lets say for an example I have a tuple like so:

```
[['citigroup.com', 'mx-a.mail.citi.com', 'Y', '248000', 'N'], ['', 'mx-b.mail.citi.com', 'Y', '', 'N']]
```

And I want to export it to csv, I could do this:

```
with open('file.csv','w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['Domain:','MX:','Verified:','ID:','>20'])
    for row in data:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

But, do I have to do something different because mine is like a tuple inside of tuple almost. When I tried I got each inner tuple as a single element. (I ended up with two elements)

How do I proprly write each tuple as a row in my csv?

**UPDATE:**

The following code works but I am getting blank rows between each is that because of the tuple inside of a tuple

```
def saveFile():
    with open('mailserverdata.csv','w') as out:
        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        csv_out.writerow(['Domain:','Mail Server:','TLS:','# of Employees:','Verified:'])
        for row in root.ptglobal.to_csv():
            csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What should your output be for the given input?

Comment: You should provide a representative sample of the code you've already written that isn't working. Tuples should be drop-in replacements for lists in the example you provided. Using tuples should make no difference. It sounds like there is just a bug in your code.

Comment: You are both right. Check my updated question.

Comment: "But lets say for an example I have a tuple like so ..."  I see no tuple.

Comment: Is that not a tuple there? Fine a list I guess then?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that's a tuple of two arrays

Comment: Ok I see what you mean.

Comment: @Kyle write every array in a new line in the csv file - I don't understand the issue

Comment: @alfasin:  Where?  I also see no arrays.  I do however see a list of lists.

Comment: That's what my loop does but now I'm getting blank lines between the rows.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski list/array whatever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correct your updated question of the extra lines in the CSV you just need to use the `wb` flag in your open statement.

So it should look like this.

```
with open('mailserverdata.csv','wb') as out:
```

It does this because the `writerow` adds a `\r\n` but then, on a Windows system, Python converts each `\n` into `\r\n` which gives you `\r\r\n`, hence the extra lines. Opening the file in binary mode prevents that from happening.

Also as @StevenRumbalski points out in the comments, this is only applicable for 2.7.

Comment: Note that this advice is applicable Python 2 only.  Python 3 csv files should be opened without the binary flag.

Comment: Not "Windows converts", but Python does the converting (assuming Python was compiled with [*Universal Newline Support*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)).  Essentially, Python allows you to be naive about platform specific newline endings converting to `'\n'` when reading files, and converting `'\n'` to whatever the platform needs when writing files.  The `csv` module prefers to not be naive about line endings, hence the need for opening the files in binary mode to get around the universal newline support.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Well Python converts because of Windows but I've updated the question to try to make that clearer who is doing what.